# Error trying to run TaskyAndroid sample Xamarin app in Visual Studio 2013/Windows 7

Tags: android, visual-studio-2013, xamarin

Steps I took:

1. Downloaded the sample "Tasky" application (Android version) from the
   Xamarin site [here](https://xamarin.com/getting-started/android).
2. Checked the "Deploy" box for the TaskAndroid project
   in the Configuration Manager.
3. Installed API 10 and API 23 of Android
   via TOOLS > Android > Android SDK Manager.
4. Cleaned + Rebuild solution.
5. Hit Ctrl-F5 and it builds successfully BUT I get the following
   deployment error:

```html
1>------ Deploy started: Project: TaskyAndroid, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
1>Error: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
========== Deploy: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

I don't even get a prompt to select an emulator.

I just updated Visual Studio 2013 to see if that would help. It didn't.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up opening the solution in Xamarin Studio and installing API 10 version of the Android SDK. This did the trick for me. When I went back to Visual Studio and reloaded the project, I was able to Ctrl-F5 and have it successfully build and deploy.